# Django models and null=True

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am creating an auction website. I have a Django model for Listings. It looks like this:

```
class Listings(models.Model):
    price = models.FloatField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    imageUrl = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="")
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="user")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="category")
    watchlist = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name="watchlistListing")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}: {self.title}, {self.description}, {self.price}, {self.imageUrl}"
```

My problem is that whenever I create a listing and try to access its 'owner' attribute, it returns 'None'. However, I can access the current user perfectly fine by using 'request.user'.

I tried removing the null=True and the blank=True parameters from the owner attribute. However this did not work and now whenever I try to access the owner attribute it just says the listing has no owner.

Comment: Did you did make migrations & migrate? and does any owner is available or its blanks in database?

Comment: Did you assign the owner while creating the object?

Comment: Share the code that is creating `Listings` objects.

Comment: You likely forgot to assign the owner when creating the object. If you did, make sure to save it afterwards. It's hard to know without a bit more context :)

Remember to assign it based on `request.user` and not let the user send their id, otherwise bad actors could create listings for other people...